# SwiftUI: Fatal Error when deleting certain Objects from Realm

Tags: list, swiftui, foreach, realm

My app crashes whenever i delete the first or second object from a list. Sometimes it'll crash when i delete other objects but this error has been inconsistent on the way it behaves. Everything looks like its done right but have not been able to figure out a fix

This is the code below

```
struct TaskView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var realmManager: RealmManager
    @ObservedResults(Task.self) var tasks
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("All Tasks").font(.title3).bold().padding().frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            List {
                ForEach(tasks, id: \.id) { task in
                        TaskRow(taskName: task.title, isDone: task.isDone).onTapGesture {
                            realmManager.updateTask(id: task.id, isDone: !task.isDone)
                        } 
                }.onDelete(perform: $tasks.remove).listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                
            }.onAppear {
                UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            }
            
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color(hue: 0.086, saturation: 0.028, brightness: 0.286))
    }
}
```

I dont understand why its so inconsistent with the crash when all objects are handled the same and the view is updated in real time

Thread 1: "Object has been deleted or invalidated."

Comment: I would guess those objects are being referenced or used in an array or other property elsewhere in code that's what's crashing - it's been deleted and then it's being modified or read hence the error.